# JavaScript Save Method can't return value only print it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function that suppose to return an object when to saves the data to db.

I need to return the value so I can pass it to the controller

can someone direct me to what is wrong here?

```
exports.addBooking = async (bookingInfo) => {
  const {
    date,
    serviceId,
    name,
    email
  } = bookingInfo
  
  
  try {
    const selectedDate = await Day.find({
      date
    });
    if (selectedDate.length > 0) {
      let day = selectedDate[0];
      day.services.map( service => {
        service.isAvailable = false;
        if (service._id == serviceId && service.reservation == null) {
          service.reservation = new Reservation({
            name,
            email,
          });

          day.save ((err, savedDate) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("Reserved", savedDate);
              return savedDate
            }
          });
        }
      })

    }

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are several problems here.  First, `return savedDate` is inside an asynchronous callback so it doesn't return to anywhere.  Second, that function call is inside a `.map()` callback so even if the first one wasn't inside an asynchronous callback, you'd only be returning from the `.map()` callback which just sets a value in the array that `.map()` returns.  Third, this is a misuse of `.map()` as it's purpose is to create a new array which you aren't using.  Fourth, you're mixing `await/promises` with plain asynchronous callbacks which is an anti-pattern as it's very difficult to control.

Comment: As for rewriting this code, it's not clear how you intend for it to work.  At the point you create a new reservation, you're inside a loop.  Do you intend to abort the loop when you create the first reservation or do you intend to possibly create more than one reservation?  Also,, what do you intend to happen in all the possible error conditions.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the clear explanation, I am trying to cover different error scenarios, but I got stuck at this point. I tried for forEach but as it was returning undefined, coudn't store its value.

Comment: It would help if you would answer the question I asked you in my 2nd comment.  I can't suggest a way to fix this without understanding the desired behavior.

Comment: @jfriend00 absolutely I want after adding the reservation to specific service in the loop to set the other attributes to false and return the all services , so I don't wanna break the loop , I need the last version to be stored in db and return a copy once it is successfully saved, as for the errors I wanted to check if there is a reservation already then break and return a message and for any other scenarios  throw an error. hopefully that clears it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the logic you want is to create a reservation for the first matching service you find and once you find one, exit your loop and return the `savedDate` (will actually be the resolved value of the promise returned), then you can do that like this:

```
const util = require('util');

exports.addBooking = async (bookingInfo) => {
    const {
        date,
        serviceId,
        name,
        email
    } = bookingInfo;

    const selectedDate = await Day.find({ date });
    if (selectedDate.length > 0) {
        const day = selectedDate[0];
        // make promisified version of .save
        if (!day.saveP) {
            day.saveP = util.promisify(day.save);
        }
        for (const service of day.services) {
            if (service._id == serviceId && service.reservation == null) {
                service.isAvailable = false;
                service.reservation = new Reservation({
                    name,
                    email,
                });
                const savedDate = await day.saveP();
                console.log("Reserved", savedDate);
                return savedDate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're after someone different business logic (which is not entirely clear in your question), then you can hopefully adapt this structure with your own business logic.

**Notes:**

1. Don't mix `await` and promises with asynchronous operations that work with plain callbacks.  Error handling and control flow are very difficult with a mixed structure.
2. Converted `day.save()` to a promisified version.  You don't say what the `day` object is, but if it already offers a promise interface, then just use that.
3. Only sets `service.isAvailable = false` if we are setting a reservation for it.  I was unclear why you were setting `service.isAvailable = false` for all services on that day.  If you actually intended to mark all services on that day, even the non-matching ones, you can move that line back to the start of the loop.
4. Once a reservation has been made and saved, the loop is terminated with a `return` statement.
5. Use `for/of` loop instead of `.map()` because it's simpler, you aren't using what `.map()` is made for (the creation of a new array) and you can exit the loop when you've made a reservation.
6. The `return savedDate` will make `savedDate` be the resolved value of the promise that the `addBooking()` function returns.

Comment: Thanks again for making the logic clear, and tough me something new like using promisify , that definitely helped my situation and I will continue to use it!

Answer (score -1):

First thing that comes to my mind is that you should await your map, as soon as map returns array of promises as I see from the code above. Also you don't assing your map to anything so basically a type of your function is `Promise<void>`.

Try using `await Promise.all` or `await Promise.allSettled`. Then you can retrieve your item from a map or throw an Error instead(or log it).

```
const [variable] = await Promise.all(%your_map_here% that should look like map(async(value) => {}))
```

Edit: also your code is a little bit complicated when it comes to a reading.
Don't use try catch on the whole block of a function, use it for the block that throws.

Comment: Thank you for the note about the use of try catch, I will keep that in mind! working on reusing the approach given by you

Comment: There's no promise being returned from the `.map()` callback and no use of `await` inside it either so this isn't going to solve anything.